# How to show rating value after clicking on the rating icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating-system

I've used [this jQuery rating](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/). [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvn4Ldmn/1/). You'll see that if you hover on the rating star icons, value of the icons will be showed at the right side(red mark on the screenshot).

[image]

But, after clicking on the icons, that value will be gone. I want that value will be kept after clicking on the icon too. How can I make this?

jQuery:

```
$('.hover-star').rating({
  focus: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('.hover-test');
    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
    tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);
  },
  blur: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('.hover-test');
    $('.hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
  }
});
```

Comment: In your fiddle value stays after a star is clicked

Answer (score 1):

The blur function is removing the text from the label. You can stop that by simply using an `if` statement.

```
  if ( type[0].data != '' )  {
      $('.hover-test').html(tip[0].data);
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvn4Ldmn/10/

If you want it so the value *only stays after you click*, you'll need to check if you have clicked as well.

```
  if ( type[0].data != '' || has_clicked == false )  {
      $('.hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
  }
```

**Note:** `has_clicked` is just an example. The "click" logic is not included in your code or fiddle. You might look at the stars for the class `star-rating-on` to determine if the user has clicked. I believe that would work.

### Update (based on comment by author)

If you want the text to preserve the value that was originally clicked on, you'll want to use a variable. The variable should be the "fall back" that was mentioned above (replacing the empty string, `''`).

You need a variable that is within the scope of your other functions. You could use a global variable (`window.variable_name`), but that's not very clean. You can also just put the variable before the other functions. Read about variable scope for more info.

```
var selected_rating = '';
```

Next, use that variable as the "fall back" for when no hover text is being displayed. Until you click on a star, this will be blank.

```
$('.hover-test').html(tip[0].data || selected_rating);
```

Finally, a couple of functions that will remember which star was previously clicked on, as well as support for the reset button.

```
 // Reset the selected rating:
 $('.rating').on('click', 'div.rating-cancel', function() {
   selected_rating = '';
   $('.hover-test').html('');
});

 // Remember a rating when it is selected:
 $('.rating').on('click', 'div.star-rating', function(e) {
   selected_rating = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('title');
   $('.hover-test').html(selected_rating);
 });
```

Fiddle / Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tvn4Ldmn/16/

Comment: if you click on the 3rd star icon, value will be set as "Ok". After you hover on any icon for example at 4th star icon, that's value("Good") will be set replacing previous "Ok". This is okay but after leaving mouse pointer that "Ok" should be returned. Because, you just hover on the 4th icon, but still 3rd icon is selected. So, "ok" shouldn't be replaced permanently until another icon is clicked.

Comment: I updated my answer to make the text stick around, and get cleared. It's based on click instead of hover. Kind of hacky, a better way is to work with the rating plugin directly instead of working alongside it, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! But I need another help. Basically I've to put multiple rating input at one page. So, those need to be independent(One rating action shouldn't affected others). To do that I've used $(this).children('.hover-test') But, it's not worked. http://jsfiddle.net/tvn4Ldmn/17/ Also at your updated fiddle, if I reset the rating by clicking "-" button and after that hover on any icon(not click), a value will set permanently again!

Comment: I would suggest doing some research with the [jQuery Star Rating Plugin - Demos](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/). Test 3-A provides a callback when you click on a star. You can use that instead of my `$('.rating').on('click', ...` code. This would also keep different ratings separated, as long as you're working with `this` instead of a jquery class selector. I couldn't reproduce your second issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvn4Ldmn/1/:

```
blur: function (value, link) {
    var tip = $('.hover-test');
    var select = $('.rating').find('.star-rating-on:last');
    if (select.length > 0) {
        tip.html(select.find('a')[0].title);
    }
}
```

What your previous code was doing (just as RadGH mentioned), was removing the text in the blur function. By looking for a clicked (selected) rating, and taking the last star element with the 'star-rating-on' class, you could effectively leave the chosen value after the mouse pointer left the rating area.